# Converting a parametric equation to non-parametric?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, curves

I am given a curve/path $\mathcal C$:

$ x=2\cos u$ and $ z=2\cosh u$ where $ 0\le u \le \frac{\pi}{2} $

The surface of rotation $\mathcal A$ is given by rotating $\mathcal C$ around the Z-axis.

Now what I'm having troubles understanding is for the curve $\mathcal C$, is y=0? or is it equivalent to some constant?

Now, for finding an equation for $\mathcal A$, do I need to transfer $\mathcal C$ to Cartesian/non parameter form first?

Comment: If the path is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then yes, $y=0$. $\mathcal{C}$ is basically the path of a particle moving in only two dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly the curve $\mathcal C$ lies in the plane $y=0$ and the surface $\mathcal A$ has for parametric equations

$$A(u,\theta) \equiv \begin{cases}
x &= 2 \cos u \cos \theta\\
y &= 2 \cos u \sin \theta\\
z &= 2 \cosh u
\end {cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Z remains the same because the rotation doesn't affect it correct? It affects only the x and y values. From what I can recall, when spinning around the z axis, it's as if x is equivalent to +/- sqrt(x^2+y2). I guess I'm just not understanding why $y=2cosusin\vartheta$

Comment: Yes correct. To find the formula I gave, I suggest that you find the image of a point of coordinates $(x,0,z)$ under the rotation of angle $\theta$ around the $z$-axis.